# For what values ​of x is true ${-(10^{10}})^{-j}\leq x \leq ({10^{10}})^{-j}$ whit $j=1,2,3...$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Can you give me any suggestions?

I understand that it is the same as

$x\leq|({10^{10}})^{-j}|$

but I don't know how to conclude

Comment: @coffeemath I already corrected it

Comment: I saw that (have already erased comment).

Comment: @coffeemath Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: See my answer... let me know if more explanation needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interpret the final phrase "with $j=1,2,3,\cdots.$" If it means just pick one of them then your answer is OK. If it means it should be true for every $k$ you need to intersect all the answers.

Comment: Could be like this? $x\in \bigcap _{ j=1 }^{ \infty  }{ ({ -10 }^{ -10j },{ 10 }^{ -10j }) } $

Comment: Yes, then finish by actually computing that intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the j is, the smaller your x should be. Therefore, if the question is for which values of x, $x≤|(10^{10})^{−j}|$ is always true no matter the j you're choosing, then the answer will be $0\leq x\leq 0$. You can prove this answer is correct by showing the limit of $|(10^{10})^{−j}|$ when j goes to $\infty$ is a number closer and closer to 0.

Comment: I see, it's a very interesting suggestion, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion for this problem? $3^{-j}\leq x \leq 2^{-j}$

Comment: This one has no specific answer for all the j's because you can be tempted to choose $x = 0$ again by the same reasons than the previous one. However $\frac{1}{3}\leq 0 \leq \frac{1}{2}$ is false. And if you choose something bigger than 0, the limit when $j$ goes to $\infty$ is the following one: $0\leq x\leq 0$ which is false again.

Comment: So how could it end?

Comment: Could you conclude by saying: not true for any value of x?

Comment: If your answer needs to be a range of values of the intersection of all x between $3^{-j}$ and $2^{-j}$ then write an empty set

Comment: I recommend you to ask your teacher if the enunciate asks for a range which is always true for any j, or otherwise, he is asking you for a range to every j

Comment: for these problems $1-2^{-j}\leq x$ and $1-10^{-j}\leq x\leq 1+10^{-j}$ its value I put $x = 1$ It is right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113454/discussion-between-martin-prado-and-gp-1729).

Comment: I think it is a range for any $j$

Comment: one last doubt.
What can I say about $a$ if $a<\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  } $

Answer (score 0):

If we extend the examples
$$1^{-1}=1\qquad0.1^{-1}=10\qquad 0.01^{-1}=100\qquad 
0.001^{-1}=100\qquad 0.0001^{-1}=10000\qquad $$
we can see that
$${10}^{-10}\le x\le 1$$
if and only if $j=1.\quad$

For $j=2\implies 10^{-5}\le x \le 1$ and the trend is not exact with j-values that do not divide 10 evenly bu it works out if $j|10$, then

$$10^{-\frac{10}{j}}\le x \le 1$$

$$10^{-5}=0.00001\quad\land\quad 0.00001^2=10000000000=10^{10}$$
$$10^{-2}=0.01\quad\land\quad 0.01^5=10000000000=10^{10}$$
$$10^{-1}=0.1\quad\land\quad 0.1^{10}=10000000000=10^{10}$$